# Найти в тексте время. Время имеет формат часы:минуты

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

> Найти в тексте время. Время имеет формат часы:минуты. И часы, и минуты состоят из двух цифр, пример: 09:00. Напишите регулярное выражение для поиска времени в строке: «Завтрак в 09:00». Учтите, что «37:98» – некорректное время. Cделать через регулярные выражения .

Вот как я пытался сделать это задание. Скажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка ?

```
string s = "Завтрак в 22:30;";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{0,1}\d{0,9}||\d{2}\d{0,3}\:\d{0,5}\d{0,9}");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(s);
if (matches.Count > 0)
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        Console.Write(match);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536768/12888024

Comment: В фигурных скобках указывается количество повторений, т.е. `\d{0,9}` — это от нуля до девяти цифр. Вам, видимо, нужно `[0-9]` вместо этого

Comment: Согласен с @aepot, но порекомендовал бы [другой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51177696/3129992) этого-же вопроса, т.к. там предлагаются варианты для 24-часового формата.

Comment: Damis, может, всё-таки посмотрите наши ответы на русском? Если какой-нибудь подходит, поставьте напротив него галочку, чтобы отметить вопрос как отвеченный.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте

```cs
\b(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\b
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3a%5b01%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c2%5b0-3%5d%29%3a%5b0-5%5d%5b0-9%5d%5cb&i=%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba+%d0%b2+22%3a30%3b)

**Подробности**

- `\b` - граница слова
- `(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])` - `0` или `1` и любая цифра или `2` и цифра от одного до трёх
- `:` - символ `:`
- `[0-5][0-9]` - цифра от нуля до пяти и любая цифра
- `\b` - граница слова

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/OBM147).

```cs
var s = "Завтрак в 22:30;";
var regex = new Regex(@"\b(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\b");
var matches = regex.Matches(s).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.Write(match);
}
// => 22:30
```

Comment: есть ли разница между `\d` и `[0-9]`?

Comment: @aepot Конечно, если вы не добавите `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`, см. [\d less efficient than \[0-9\]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970). Моё регулярное выражения можно объявить так: `new Regex(@"\b(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d\b", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)`.

Answer (score -1):

В фигурных скобках пишется количество, а не диапазон. Диапазон пишется в квадратных скобках через тире. `[0-5][0-9]`, `[0-5]\d`, `[0-5]?\d`. В принципе, `\d{2}` и `\d{1,2}` тоже могут прокатить. Ну и остальные куски аналогично.

И `||` тоже не в тему.

PS: `\d` в шарпе также найдёт региональные цифры, если вдруг такие есть в тексте.